# Run my Winrt application through IntelliTraceCollector

Tags: debugging, winrt-xaml, intellitrace

I need to collect .iTrace files from my Winrt application without debuging at Visual Studio.

I try to use, this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh398365.aspx

but I have a problem with path to my application  C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe

C:\IntelliTraceCollector\IntelliTraceSC.exe launch /cp:"C:\IntelliTraceCollector\collection_plan.ASP.NET.default.xml" /f:"C:\IntelliTraceLogFiles\MyApp.itrace" "C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the following folder and files exists:
C:\IntelliTraceCollector\IntelliTraceSC.exe 
C:\IntelliTraceCollector\collection_plan.ASP.NET.default.xml
C:\IntelliTraceLogFiles\
C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe